# Execute a Python file in GNU Octave

Tags: python, octave, gnu

I write a code to run a python file in GNU Octave. This is that code part.

```
[output,status]=python('customers.py');
output
status
```

But when execute that code I get an error like this.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
output =
status =  1
```

I don't understand why I got an error like this. The python file is also in the same directory.
This is the python code:

```
# Import sys module
import sys

# Total number of arguments
print('Total arguments:', len(sys.argv))

#print("Argument values are:")
# Iterate command-line arguments using for loop
#for i in sys.argv:
  #print(i)

# Define a dictionary
customers = {'9876':'Kamal Perera','9873':'Amal Fernando',
'9865':'Vimal Gunasena','9843':'Chamal Sirisena', '9862':'Dumal Zoysa',
'9831':'Nimal Walpola'}

#print("The customer names are:")
# Print the values of the dictionary
#for customer in customers:
    #print(customers[customer])

# Take customer ID as input to search
print("Search customer ID:",sys.argv[1])
name = sys.argv[1]
# Search the ID in the dictionary
for customer in customers:
    if customer == name:
        print(customers[customer])
        break
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python` command is effectively a wrapper to the `system` command, which calls the operating system's `python` command for you.

If the system's `python` executable is not on the system PATH, then obviously octave will fail to find it.

Judging from the error I'm guessing you're on windows? In which case, look up how to add python to your PATH in windows.

(e.g. here's a random first link from a duckduckgo search: https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ )

Alternatively, you can use `getenv("PATH")` to check what your current system path is, and modify it from within octave to concatenate that string with the python executables directory, and then set it using `setenv("PATH")`

**EDIT (2023)**: Another (and probably better) option to interface with python is the octave-pythonic package: https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/pythonic / https://gitlab.com/mtmiller/octave-pythonic

Comment: Thanks so much, @Tasos Papastylianou I've marked this as the answer. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks @HarshanaWalpita. Note that in StackOverflow, the up/down arrows are simply for voting (which anyone can do). To mark the answer as correct, click on the 'tick' _under_ the votes (which only the person asking the question can do).